# Appending a list of dict in another nested list of dict with checking the parents

Tags: python, list, dictionary, yaml

I am trying to append a dict in a nested list of dict, while checking for the same parents and then appending at appropriate location. My input `dicts` and required output are for example:

**Input**:

```
Dict1 = [{'name':'A', 
          'childs':[{
                'name':'B', 
                'childs':[{
                      'name':'C',
                       'childs':[{
                             'name':'D', 
                             'childs': None}]}]}]},
          {'name':'E', 'childs':None}]
Dict2=[{'name':'B',
        'childs':[{
              'name':'C',
              'childs':[{
                    'name':'X', 
                    'childs':None}]}]}]
```

Output :-

```
Dict1 = [{'name':'A', 
          'childs':[{
                'name':'B', 
                'childs':[{
                      'name':'C',
                       'childs':[{
                             'name':'D', 
                             'childs': None},
                            {'name':'X' , 
                             'childs':None}}]}]},
          {'name':'E' , 'childs':None}]
```

It is just appending a dictionary as a child of another dictionary, but I am not able to figure out, how can I check for the same parents while iterating in both dictionaries and then append.

Comment: Is 'name' always unique in the same dictionary or can it be duplicated?

Comment: @ishez the value for key 'name' is always unique in the same dictionary.

Comment: Is it possible that items in Dict2 don't have same parents of Dict1?

Comment: yes... its quite possible

Comment: @ishez .. what will you do if both have same parent. For example if dict2 is [{'name':'A', 'childs':[{ 'name':'B', 'childs':[{     'name':'X', 'childs':None}]}]}] and its always true that if the first child is not same in dict then it should append right there... I hope I am able to quote properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_dict_with_name(name, list_of_dicts):
     ''' 
     returns the dict that has the same name as name from list_of_dicts
     assured a dict or None
     '''
     if not list_of_dicts:
         return None

     for _dict in list_of_dicts:
         if name == _dict['name']:
             return _dict
         # check children as well
         dict_from_children = get_dict_with_name(name, _dict['childs'])
         if dict_from_children:
             return dict_from_children

     return None

 def append_stuff(list_of_dicts_1, list_of_dict_2):
     ''' 
     iter through all of list_of_dict_2, and merge with 1
     '''
     if not list_of_dict_2:
         return
     if not list_of_dicts_1:
         return

     for _dict in list_of_dict_2:
         name = _dict['name']
         dict_in_1 = get_dict_with_name(name, list_of_dicts_1)
         # if u dont get a dict, simply add it as a new dict to the list
         if not dict_in_1:
             list_of_dicts_1.append(_dict)
             continue

         # if you found, now check with children - each of these children in that dict
         append_stuff(dict_in_1['childs'], _dict['childs'])
```

It adds it to list_of_dicts_1. That should do it.
However, since it has this hierarchy, maybe constructing a tree structure would be more useful to you.

In your inputs, youve called the two lists Dict1 and Dict2
so here, you call append_stuff(Dict1, Dict2)
and Dict1 has the required output.

Comment: I've written a cleaner version with a tree like structure. If u feel it is useful, I can update the answer here. Here you go - [code link](http://pastebin.com/PxtDNkUa)

Comment: This code is working fine for me and I just had put a few changes to make it bidirectional. I will appreciate if you can post the tree structure code here. I am getting access denied as I am working through my company network.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Methodology description

I propose the following methodology:

- `gen_base` generates a data-base from the given dictionary lists containing the childes and the parents. The data base is a dictionary that helps the indexation of the different elements. It contains elements such as `{..., 'B': {'childs': ['C'], 'parent': 'A'}, ...}`
- `build_tree` creates a method that build the tree of a given name using the generated data-base.
- `merge_from_base` merges the data-base element to form a complete tree.

Here are the methods:

### 2. Example of execution

Let `Dict1` and `Dict2` be the lists of dictionaries you have given as examples and `Dict3` the required result.

```
>>> base = gen_base(Dict1 + Dict2)
>>> base
{'A': {'childs': ['B'], 'parent': None},
 'B': {'childs': ['C'], 'parent': 'A'},
 'C': {'childs': ['D', 'X'], 'parent': 'B'},
 'D': {'childs': [], 'parent': 'C'},
 'E': {'childs': [], 'parent': None},
 'X': {'childs': [], 'parent': 'C'}}

>>> res = merge_from_base(base=base,)
>>> res
[{'name': 'A', 'childs': [
    {'name': 'B', 'childs': [
        {'name': 'C', 'childs': [
            {'name': 'D', 'childs': None,},
            {'name': 'X', 'childs': None,}],}],}],},
 {'name': 'E', 'childs': None,}]

>>> res == Dict3
True
```

### 3. Sources

```
#
# 1. Generate a data base
#
def gen_base(lst, parent=None, res=None):
    """Generates a data-base with childes and parents"""
    if res is None: res = {}    # res will contain the required result
    if lst is None: return res  # Given list (in our case, it is Dict1 + Dict2)
    for d in lst:   # For each element d in the list ...
        if d['name'] in res:    # ... if the name exists in the data-base,
            if res[d['name']]['childs'] is None:    # if it has no child
                res[d['name']]['childs'] = []
            else:                                   # if there are children
                for c in d['childs']:               # get teir names in a list
                    if c['name'] not in res[d['name']]['childs']:
                        res[d['name']]['childs'].append(c['name'])
        else:                   # ... if the name does not exist in the base
            res[d['name']] = {  # ... create a new one
                'childs':[] if d['childs'] is None else [c['name'] for c in d['childs']],
                'parent':parent}
        # In any case, do the same for children (recursively)
        gen_base(d['childs'], parent=d['name'], res=res)
    return res

#
# 2. Build a tree from a root and a data-base
#
def build_tree(base, root):
    """Builds the tree of the given root using informations from the base"""
    ret = {}    # The result will contain a name and a list of childes
    ret['name'] = root  # The root is a string such as 'A', 'B', ...
    if base[root]['childs'] == []:
        ret['childs'] = None
        # If there are no children, the tree stops
    else:
        # # If there are children, the tree continues to grow recursively
        ret['childs'] = map(lambda e: build_tree(base, e), base[root]['childs'])
    return ret

#
# 3. Merge the data
#
def merge_from_base(base,):
    """Uses the base to get the roots (which 'parent' is None) and complete the trees"""
    ret = []
    for p in base:
        if base[p]['parent'] is None:   # The final list contains the roots
            # ... and the roots point to their children
            ret.append(build_tree(base=base, root=p))
    return ret
```

Seriously Taha,

Comment: thanks for this code, its the tree traversal approach.... Mostly with the yaml files, which are created as config files, I would rather append everything as a child and not to worry about parent node. But this methodology shows a new way around .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly modified one with a Node class, to build the same structure. I feel the core logic is much more easier to understand here.

```
$> cat input.txt ( From your sample input )
{'d2': [{'childs': [{'childs': [{'childs': None, 'name': 'X'}], 'name': 'C'}], 'name': 'B'}], 'd1': [{'childs': [{'childs': [{'childs': [{'childs': None, 'name': 'D'}], 'name': 'C'}], 'name': 'B'}], 'name': 'A'}, {'childs': None, 'name': 'E'}]}

$>vi test1.py (sorry for the name, your question was too long)
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
    ''' not making children None, [] is easier to work with '''
        self.name = name
        self.children = []

    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

    def flatten_to_dict(self):
        ''' to get it back to your format '''
        my_dict = {'name': self.name, 'childs': []}

        for child in self.children:
            my_dict['childs'].append(child.flatten_to_dict())

        return my_dict

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(inp_dict):
        ''' taking the input as dictionaries - your format converter '''
        root = Node(inp_dict['name'])
        if not inp_dict['childs']:
            return root

        for child in inp_dict['childs']:
            root.add_child(Node.from_dict(child))
        return root

    def __repr__(self):
        ''' u know what this is for '''
        return "%s" % self.flatten_to_dict()

    def find_node_with_name(self, name):
        if self.name == name:
            return self

        for child in self.children:
            found_node = child.find_node_with_name(name)
            if found_node:
                return found_node
        return None

    @staticmethod
    def merge_nodes(node1, node2):
        ''' the actual core logic, very simple '''
        the_node = node1.find_node_with_name(node2.name)

        if not the_node:
            return None

        for child in node2.children:
            n = Node.merge_nodes(the_node, child)
            if not n:
                the_node.add_child(child)
        return the_node

    def merge_with_node(self, another_node):
        ''' want to return a new instance, not modify current node, so a wrapper
        for a static function, one time new instance, and then modify that in place '''

        # creating a new instance by deseriazling the serialized object
        # since i dont want this to happen recursively, hence the wrapper
        node_to_return = Node.from_dict(self.flatten_to_dict())
        x = Node.merge_nodes(node_to_return, another_node)
        return node_to_return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ''' preprocessing, so we can work with the Node class'''
    data = eval(open('input.txt').read())
    d1 = data['d1'] # first list of data dicts
    d2 = data['d2'] # second list of data dicts
    # as per you're input example of Dict1 and Dict2
    Dict1 = map(Node.from_dict, d1)
    Dict2 = map(Node.from_dict, d2)

    # assuming Dict2 should just be one element, then Dict2[0]
    Dict2 = Dict2[0]
    result = []
    # try to merge with every dict in Dict1
    for _dict in Dict1:
        res = _dict.merge_with_node(Dict2)
        result.append(res)

    print result


$>python test1.py
```